# How do I reference a category and use its methods in a class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, class, categories

I'm having trouble referencing and using my categories for a class I made. The class is GameViewController and it has many methods, I want to clean up the code. I asked earlier and was told the best way to do so is with a category. Now I'm a bit confused as to how to reference the category in the .m file. Do I simply `#import 'class+categoryname'`or is there a different way to do it. Thanks. Shen Hutah.

Comment: if its your own class why don't you simply inherit it to make make new exclusive methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/categories.html will teach you how.

But it's really easy. After creating the category simply #import "file.categoryName.h" then reference as you would without a category. They're useful for keeping code clean when there is a lot of code.

Answer (score 2):

Categories are a way to modularize a class by spreading its implementation over many files. Extensions provide similar functionality, except its API must be declared in the main implementation file.

Here is a good and short article to understand the Categories and extension:

http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/categories.html

Comment: Thanks, this was a user friendly article.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 steps for your app to make use of categories

1. Importing resolves compilation issue.

2.Add it to build phase as shown in pic

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you just add `#import "TheClass+categoryname.h"` and use function in the class:

```
TheClass *object = [[TheClass alloc] init];
[object function_defined_in_TheClass_+_categoryname];
```